# jQuery, class of selected item from selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following html:

```
<div class="form-group select optional reservation_reception_location">
 <select class="select optional form-control" id="reservation_reception_location_id" name="reservation[reception_location_id]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option class="Office" value="1">Oddział Częstochowa</option>
   <option class="Airport" value="2">dasdasd</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Now my goal is to know the class of selected element. So when i select the first one i will assign its class to value in my coffescript file. I tried something like this:

```
$('#reservation_reception_location_id').attr('class')
```

But this show me main div class only.
I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)** selector to get the selected option:

```
$('#reservation_reception_location_id option:selected').attr('class')
```

If you want to get the selected option when your `select` has been changed, then use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event:

```
$('#reservation_reception_location_id').change(function() {
    var cls = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class');
    console.log(cls);    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g7htM/)**

Comment: This solution is more optimized.

Comment: @Superdrac What do you mean by more optimized? Compare to what?

Comment: To the find just below.

Comment: @Superdrac So that's wrong, `.find()` is more performant even difference could be count in nano seconds

Comment: Ok sorry Wolff, and thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#reservation_reception_location_id').change(function(){
  var selectedClass=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("class");
});
```